# Javascript object, Node and Jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I create a object in a Node server and a send it throught Jade:

```
module.exports = class Object {
    constructor() {
        this.foo = "bar";
    }

    getFoo() {
        return this.foo;
    }
}
```

Server.js file:

```
var ob = new Object();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index', {object : ob});
});
```

When I try to use the object on the client

```
var ob = !{JSON.stringify(object)};
console.log(ob.getFoo());
```

I get the error that the variable "ob" has no function "getFoo", the client requests object.js where is described the Object class.
I don't think this is the right way, but it's the only one I know.

First question, non native English speaker, hope everything is at least fine.

Comment: `class Object`. That's as bad as it can get. Choose another name for your class, don't use existing names that belong to native types.

Comment: @Luca it thows an error here.

Comment: @Luca No. It's Jade as mentioned... In plain JS it would've been invalid syntax since a block is not an expression

Comment: It's also not clear what you mean by, 'When I try to use the object on the client'. Are you talking about using the object and function in you jade template, or in a script run in the browser. The later is not going to work — you can't stringify the function.

Comment: To OP: Because you're stringifying the object, it's now a JSON string. A string doesn't have the method anymore. You'll have to find a way to return the object back into its instance form (assuming you rename it from `Object`)...

Comment: `JSON.stringify` strips all functions (and some other stuff too) from your object. `JSON.stringify({a: 5, b: function() {}})` => `{"a":5}`

Comment: Yes, the name is Object just to be clear, I'll try to pass the object in others way, thanks to everyone! You all really rock!